Proguard not removing Logs from AAR dependency
My andorid app depends on an aar file. The aar comes with its own proguard file inside. So I unzipped the aar and added the following in the proguard file:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

I then rezipped the aar and compiled my app. Here is the relevant part of my apps's build.gradle:
release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources (findProperty('android.enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }

Proguard is removing all logs from my own app. But I can still see logs coming from the aar.
What am I missing?

.aar won't work after unzipping and rezipping. You need to find the source of that aar file and make changes as per your requirement and then generate the binary. If you got stuck in any step you can ask here only by editing your question and adding all the necessary code.

@BobSmith But the aar is working. The functions are being invoked from it without issues.

@BobSmith Can you please explain why do you think a rezipped .aar does not work anymore (assuming that it wasn't signed)?

yes it won't work changing the way @effendi is doing. Robert if you have Any better approach you can suggest him.
